# where is NSString literal placed in memory?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, nsstring, string-literals

I made a test for NSString.

```
int a = 10;
NSString *str1 = @"str";
NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"str"];
NSString *str3 = @"str";
NSString *str4 = @"str2";
NSLog(@"%p %p | 3 %p | 4 %p | a %p", str1,str2,str3,str4,&a);
```

result is

```
0x1286287c8 0xa000000007274733 | 3 0x1286287c8 | 4 0x1286287e8 | a 0x7ffeeb215b14
```

this test placed in iPhone 6s(11.1) Simulator. So what's the place of `str1` in memory? is it Stack or Heap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that your curious value, `0xa000000007274733`, is *odd* - that is the least significant bit is set. Object pointers are usually even - see the other ones you've displayed.

An odd-valued pointer is an indicator that it might be one of Apple's *tagged pointers*, where instead of allocating an object the data is stored directly in the pointer itself.

The Unicode for `r` is 0x72, `s` & `t` follow. So it looks like you have the Unicode for the characters in there.

Mike Ash did a [good article](https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-07-31-tagged-pointer-strings.html) on tagged strings back in 2015, though your value doesn't seem to match the scheme he discovered. However I'd go with this being a tagged pointer of some kind.

HTH

**Addendum**

I see you edited the question to ask whether the literal is in the stack or heap, and that made be realise you were asking about `str1`, oops. The literal will be in a "data segment", in the same area of memory as the code.

To see this try allocating a general object (an `NSObject` will do, but not an `NSString` which tend to get special treatment) to see where a heap object goes, and taking the address of a C function to see where the code goes. You'll probably find `str1` is closest to the latter.

Comment: first thanks for you giving me a answer so quickly. but ```0xa000000007274733 ``` is not odd,  you see ```a0 00 00 00 07 27 47 33```, it should be 8 bytes. as we know, 6s is 64 bits architecture. however you give me a clue on odd value like ```0x1286287e8``` that a string literal printed. thanks again.

Comment: The least significant digit of the pointer value is a `3`, which is odd, its not the first byte in memory that needs to be odd but the 8 bytes interpreted as an address. The high order `a` doesn't match the scheme Mike Ash describes either, but I'd still guess it is a tagged pointer.

Comment: so do you think ``` 0x1286287c8 (str1's address)``` is a address point to "data segment"? As mentioned above ``` The literal will be in a "data segment", in the same area of memory as the code.``` And I want to clarify ``` literal ``` mentioned here is like ```@"123" @(123) @[@"123"] @{@"key1":@"value"} ``` that I think a literal as is.

Comment: For Objective-C literal integers, floats and strings will all probably be compiled into the code/data area. However array and dictionary literals are (at least currently) compiled to code which constructs the value at runtime on the heap. `NSNumber` literals could be compiled to code which constructs them at runtime, to tagged pointer values, or directly into the code/data like non-object numeric literals; I haven't tested which method is currently used - I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: actually i did the exercise. result may confirmed your answer that is ```generic obj 0x6040002039a0 | nsnumber literal 0xb000000000000012 | array literal 0x6040002039b0```, as you can see, array literal's address is more  like a generic object, and number literal more likely string literal but here first bit is a ```b```.

Comment: The answer is **it is an implementation detail**.  It will change from release to release.   And, in fact, if the address is odd, then there may not be an allocation *at all* as the string's value is actually encoded into the address of the object.   But only on some platforms because the implementation details of tagged pointers has changed from release to release and arch to arch, too.

Comment: @iWenPro See last comment.  `0xb......12` likely means it is a tagged pointer and **there is no allocation at all**.   As well, string constants are, technically, not backed by an allocation, either.  They are loaded as a part of the mach-o file.

Comment: @bbum ```They are loaded as a part of the mach-o file.``` This reflects what @CRD said above ```string literal``` from ```data segment```. Still some thing weird I found here is a generic object like ```generic obj 0x6040002039a0 ```  is six bytes not 8 bytes which I think an arm 64 should has.

Comment: @iWenPro - You are confusing number of hex digits in the formatted representation of a value with the number of bits in the value. Most formats don't print leading zeroes unless this is specifically set, and `%p` doesn't even accept the leading zero format flag.

Comment: @CRD oops, i mixed it. there's some thing not perfect about ''str" unicode maps  ```\u0073\u0074\u0072 ```. however still interesting for your answer address contains data itself.

Comment: @CRD I did another test using 'string' and found the rule. It printed ```0xa00676e697274736 ``` , the last `6` here means six chars in the address. and then all the chars are ``` \u0073\u0074\u0072\u0069\u006e\u0067 ``` which are 'string' unicode. so read it from right to left maps the unicode correctly.  And `str` address above also following this rule. LOL

Comment: tagged point for number also matches what I said above except the last bit should means a type which I tested ``` int ->2 long->3 float->4 ``` @bbum

Answer (score 2):

> So what's the place of str1 in memory? is it Stack or Heap?

A string -- an Objective-C object -- ***can never be on the stack* ***.   Stack based ObjC objects have never been supported.

An Objective-C object can be in one of three places, though.  Well, two, really, and the third is weird.

1. An object can be on the heap.  It is, effectively, in a hunk of memory that was `malloc()`d (though not always `malloc()`, but that is an implementation detail) and the first 4 (32 bit) or 8 (64 bit) bytes will be a pointer to the class of the object and, possibly, some metadata encoded into said pointer (i.e. don't just grab the `isa` and think you've got a valid class).
2. An object may be in the readonly memory that is mapped into memory by dyld.  These objects are actually created by the linker and are a part of the executable.   NSString constants fall into this category.  NSArray and NSDictionary constants do not;  they are still dynamically allocated as per (1) above.   Note one oddity;  because they are not allocated, they do not follow the string 16 byte (typically) aligned allocation patterns of (1).  In fact, they may be 2 byte aligned (they won't likely be odd, but that's another implementation detail that may change).
3. They may be a tagged pointer.  If the lowest order bit is set-- an odd address-- that means "tagged pointer".   But that, too, is an implementation detail that can-- and has-- changed.   With a tagged pointer, **there is no allocation at all**.   The "pointer" isn't a pointer at all.  The pointer is the data;  for an `NSNumber`, the value and type of the contained number is encoded in the object "pointer".

---

- The one exception is a Block.  They can be in the heap, in the memory mapped data segment loaded by the executable, or ***on the stack***.

However, that's another implementation detail.  Only, in this case, you are exposed to it.   While the compiler, under ARC, actually makes it largely fully automatic at this time, there are still a couple of cases where you need to copy a block to ensure it moves to the heap before the declarative scope disappears.

However, since the class of a Block isn't exposed nor is there any means of manually allocating Blocks, I'm going to stick with Objective-C objects never being on the stack.  ;)